# CSS for Nested DIV tags

Tags: html, css

I have nested div as shown below:

```
<div class="abc">
   <div class="bcd">
   </div>
</div>
```

I have a grid to which i have assigned the class "abc" and i am using edit template of grid to which i have assigned the class "bcd". Now problem is table of 2nd div has assigned the css for first div..

What shud i do inorder to assign only bcd class to 2nd div and it should not take abc,,

Thanking you

Regards,

Dhaval Shukla

Comment: It would be easier if you posted your CSS code here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS inheritance works on a property by property basis. When applied to an element in a document, a property with the value 'inherit' will use the same value as the parent element has for that property.

If you dont want the styles for `abc` in the `bcd` class you will need to set them in the `bcd` class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can't.

CSS is "cascading style sheets".  "Cascading" partly suggests that the styles "cascade" (fall) down to the elements below, like a waterfall.

The only way around this is to explicitly define the properties you want on the specific child class.

Answer (score -1):

you may create css classes like following

```
.abc{

your specification

}
.abc > div{

your specification

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The class 'bcd' is inheriting CSS properties from it's parent 'abc'. What you can do is:

1. Add !important to the end of the styles that are getting overwritten, to prevent the style from being overwritten.
2. Assign a unique ID to the div's and style the ID's. This obviously depends on your application though.

When using classes, inheriting properties is useful as you don't have to re-write style rules again.